# Is it possible to change the cypress.config.ts/cypress.config.js location instead of have it on the root of the project?

Tags: cypress

Is a way to change the`cypress.config.ts` file's location instead of having it in the root of the project along with the `package.json`, `tsconfig.json`?

I changed the file (cypress.config.ts) location but it doesn't work I got an error message :

> Could not find a Cypress configuration file in this folder:
> /Users/Mycomputer/cypressDemoPomExample

Answer (score 2):

I figure out how to fix it

You can simply run the command :

```js
npx cypress open --config-file theNewCypressConfigPath
```